# Validation Rule to restrict Non-Support Profile users from Reopening Closed Cases

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I have created a validation rule to restrict Non-Support Profile users from Reopening Support Cases. Only members of Customer Support are allowed to reopen support cases. But it is not getting fired Currently.
Here is the criteria for validation rule :
As a Non-Support member, when attempting to reopen a support case that has the status of closed, my action is not completed. If user's profile is Sales related and the case record type is either "Support," "Support - New," or "Support - Closed" AND the case's Status is "Closed" & user attempts to update the Status to "Reopened," validation should fire.

Here is my Validation Rule:

```
AND(
TEXT(Status) <> "Closed",
ISCHANGED(Status),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status), "Closed"),
OR(
RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Support',
RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Support_New',
RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Support_Closed'
),

OR(
$Profile.Name = 'AB - Sales',
$Profile.Name = 'XYZ - Sales'
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AND(
   NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Closed')), /* Compare to API Value in case we change Label. This is redundant given the combination of ISCHANGED() and PRIORVALUE() */
   OR(
      ISNEW(), /* ISCHANGED() does not fire on new records. */
      AND(
         ISCHANGED(Status),
         ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status), 'Closed')
      ),
   ),
   OR(
      RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Support',
      RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Support_New',
      RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Support_Closed'
   ),
   CONTAINS($Profile.Name, 'Sales') /* Shot in the dark here, not knowing what other profile names you have */
)
```